# Disassembler that tracks what value is where

Tags: disassembly

So lately I've been looking at the disassembly of my C++ code, and having to manually track what's in each register, like this:

```
  95:   48 8b 16                mov    (%rsi),%rdx ; %rdx = raggedCross.sink
  98:   48 8b 42 38             mov    0x38(%rdx),%rax ; %rax = sink.table
  9c:   8b 4a 10                mov    0x10(%rdx),%ecx ; %ecx = sink.baseCol
  9f:   48 8b 70 50             mov    0x50(%rax),%rsi ; %rsi = table.starts
  a3:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax   ; %eax = baseCol
  a5:   83 c1 1c                add    $0x1c,%ecx  ; %ecx = baseCol + 1
```

And so on.  The comments are mine, added by hand, from looking up the offset of various fields (e.g. sink, table, baseCol, starts) in the C++ classes.

It's straight forward to do, but tedius and time consuming: the perfect thing for a program to be doing.  gdb seems to know the offset of various fields within a struct: I can do &((Table *)0x1200)->starts and it tells the the right address.  So, this information is around.

Is there some disassembler that can use this info to annotate the code for me?

Failing that, I could write my own.  Where does gdb get the offsets?

Answer (score 0):

GDB uses the debugging information you included to determine that sort of thing, it's not part of a normal executable; [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) is one common format used to store debug information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debugging information (DWARF2) in order to look at the object files. As you're using GCC, you can do an annotated dump using the binutils utility `objdump -S`. If you dump all sections, the DWARF information is dumped as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/). It won't completely automate the process, but it'll at least let you define your structure/class in one place, and it'll handle most things from there.